# Why there is no 'Task Scheduler Library' appear in my Task Scheduler. Also, I can't create a task or do anything with it

Tags: windows-10, boot, keyboard, windows-task-scheduler

Well, I had a problem with my windows startup, where I can't type anything on my search windows. So I had to run *'C:\Windows\system32\ctfmon.exe'* every time to fix it (yea, I know there're also some alternative ways to fix it).

Then, I found an answer on this [link](http://www.talenteddeveloper.co.in/enable-ctfmon-exe-on-startup-via-task-scheduler/), written as **'Enable Ctfmon.Exe on Startup via Task Scheduler:'**.

Then, when I open my Task Scheduler, there is no task or the *Task Scheduler Library*. I can't even create any task, [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk0y9.png). This what happens when I try to click [Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRl9T.png) in the Task Scheduler.

I also made some research, to run [**'taskschd.msc'**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCeuw.png) (I'm sorry, I don't know what it means, just following a tutorial). Then it appears to say *'The remote computer is not found'.*

I tried to find other problems on the internet that is similar to mine, but I can't find any solution that suitable.

Can someone please, explain to me what's happening to my windows and tell me how any of these problems should work. I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Try the initial repair for Windows 10:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Adminstrator;  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup  ; dism.exe /online /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  ; SFC /SCANNOW  ;  Restart when done and test.

Comment: Your windows is damaged. The not being able to type anything into search should be your indicator that you need to fix things rather than find alternative ways. Things broke more and task scheduler also doesn't work. Might be a cortana issue. Did you by any chance tried to uninstall it using a powershell script? I recommend reinstalling windows.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reasonably certain way to repair a corrupted or damaged Windows Operating System is a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to
> create a USB Windows Installation key, then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

**First:**

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

If this does not work as expected,

**Second:**

You can also Keep Data, or Keep Nothing. Keep Nothing is very close to a clean install.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I did reinstall my windows and it worked! Everything's fine now, and the Task Scheduler also fixed. Appreciate your help and other comments too.